# Android NDK timers

Tags: java, android, c, java-native-interface, android-ndk

I wrote a piece of code in c to calculate how long a section of the C code was taking, then trying to report it back to the Java code.  But the problem is that the timer differential always comes back as zero.  here is the native C

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h> /* sleep() */
#include <time.h>
#include <jni.h>

jstring Java_com_nsf_ndkfoo_NDKFooActivity_invokeNativeFunction(JNIEnv* env, jobject javaThis) {

    time_t start, end;

    start = time(NULL);
    if(start == (time_t)-1) {
      return 1;
    }

    sleep(5);

    end = time(NULL);

    char buf[60] = { 0 };

    sprintf(buf,"according to difftime(), slept for %.8f seconds\n", (int)difftime(end, start));

    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, buf);
}
```

When I run this I always get "according to difftime(), slept for -0.00000000 seconds".  Any ideas what's wrong?

--------------------------------**Final Code Solution**--------------------------------------------------------

This is what I found finally works not sure why as I am not a C guru but here it is anyway.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h> /* sleep() */
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <jni.h>

jstring Java_com_nsf_ndkfoo_NDKFooActivity_invokeNativeFunction(JNIEnv* env, jobject javaThis) {

    struct timeval start;
    struct timeval end;

    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
    sleep(5);

    gettimeofday(&end, NULL);

    char buf[60] = { 0 };

    sprintf(buf,"according to difftime(), slept for %ld seconds\n",  ((end.tv_sec * 1000000 + end.tv_usec) - (start.tv_sec * 1000000 + start.tv_usec)));

    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, buf);
}
```

Java code for android looks like this:

```
package com.nsf.ndkfoo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class NDKFooActivity extends Activity {
    // load the library - name matches jni/Android.mk
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("ndkfoo");
    }

    // declare the native code function - must match ndkfoo.c
    private native String invokeNativeFunction();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // this is where we call the native code
        String hello = invokeNativeFunction();

        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(hello).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: We only handle usage questions here, dev questions go on [SO].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using `gettimeofday()` to measure time.  I have successfully used it with the NDK, although in my case it was with `pthread_cond_timedwait()`.

Answer (score 2):

See this reference.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/difftime/

```
/* difftime example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main ()
{
  time_t start,end;
  char szInput [256];
  double dif;

  time (&start);
  printf ("Please, enter your name: ");
  gets (szInput);
  time (&end);
  dif = difftime (end,start);
  printf ("Hi %s.\n", szInput);
  printf ("It took you %.2lf seconds to type your name.\n", dif );

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I already ran this version of the code using timers and still got 0 secs. That is why I went a different route with the code above.  Must be something with Native calls and system clock.

Answer (score 2):

Use gettimeofday() like this:

```
bool QueryPerformanceCounter( int64_t* performance_count )
{
    struct timeval Time;

    /* Grab the current time. */
    gettimeofday( &Time, NULL );
    *performance_count = Time.tv_usec + /* Microseconds. */
                         Time.tv_sec * usec_per_sec; /* Seconds. */

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the return code for sleep() to ensure that 0 is returned, meaning the 5 seconds have expired.  Maybe the bionic libc implementation of sleep is not working properly in your environment (emulator/device).  Or try and increase the number of seconds to sleep to 60 and add some print statements before and after to ensure that the minute is sleep occurs.